# I need to add button to keyboard like following picture

Tags: iphone

image is at following location

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e50107df44.jpg

please help me.

i will be thank full to you.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866532/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually trivial.  What you have there is just a UIToolbar perched above the keyboard -- it's not attached to the keyboard in any way at all, except to the extent that you program it to be.

The biggest problem with doing one that way is that if the keyboard slides in and out, you probably want the toolbar to do the same, which requires some careful coordination of the animation speed.

More specifically, you want to trigger the appearance of the toolbar in

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

and its disappearance in the method invoked with the Termine button is touched.

Do you need more details?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that looks like the new-in-3.0 UIWebView form autofill bar. I'm sure it is internally implemented like you say, a UIToolbar that appears when the keyboard does but you cannot add any more buttons to it. I'm not sure if that is what sagar is asking for or not though.